# Wake on Lan over Internet without Custom Firmware for LINKSYS WAG200G

Tags: router, wake-on-lan

I'm using LINKSYS WAG200G modem router and I would like to turn on my computer over internet.

I managed to turn it on over lan/wlan, however I'm having hard times turning it on over internet.

What I understood with a packet sniffer (notice that I have a public static ip, let's call it S.S.S.S) is that this packet sent never reached my computer (well, through lan is possible, but I can't find a way to make it reach through internet).

I would like to avoid installing a custom firmware, expecially because I'm going to buy a new router in a while and I don't even know if I can install a custom firmware on it.

I don't understand if is something "filtered" by isp (I asked them and they said they don't filter anything), or a firewall blocking it, but I turned everything off.

Do anyone know how to solve this? I found a lot of resources over the net, but everything involves overwriting the firmware with a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, it is not possible. Routers blocks WOL Packet from the internet, the only way to solve this is access to the router, and if it supports sending WOL from there, it will be possible to WOL your computers.